# ASP.NET MVC 3: what and when to cache and how to decide?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been neglecting learning about caching for quite some time now, and although I've used caching here and there in the past it's not something I'm familiar with.

I found a great tutorial about [what caching is and what kinds of cache there are](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) (I know already what caching is), but...

How does one decide what and when to cache? Are there things that should *always* be cached? On what situations should you *never* use caching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rule is: Don't cache until you need it, that would be [premature optimization](http://30sleeps.com/blog/2007/12/10/premature-optimization/) (first link I found, google for more info)

The biggest problem with caching is invalidation of cache. What happens when the data you have cached is being updated. You need to make sure your cache is updated as well and if not done correctly often becomes a mess.

I would:

1. Build the application without
   caching and make sure the
   functionality works as intended
2. Do some performance testing, and
   apply caching when needed
3. After applying caching do
   performance testing again to check
       that you are getting the expected speed increase

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to ask yourself a bunch of questions,

**Is this result ever going to change?**

**No?** then cache it permanently

**Yes,** When is it going to change? When a **user** updates something. 
Is it going to impact only the particular user who changed the value or all of the users. This should give you an indication of when to clear the particular cache.

You can keep on going, but after awhile you will end up with different profiles
UserCache, GlobalCache just being 2 examples. 
These profiles should be able to tell you what to cache and have a certain update criteria (When to refresh the cache)